# How to make text input line up with button in IE7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I'm trying to get an `<input />` to line up correctly next to a `<button>` in IE7.

Ideally, the rendered HTML should appear as: (or similar)

[image]

but instead it's appearing as

[image]

This is an example of the HTML/CSS I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/wLpQg/1/

Note how the textbox appears on a different line to the button. This works correctly in all browsers except IE7 (and maybe IE6, but I haven't checked that!)

How can I get this to appear on the same line as the button, preferably as similarly to the first image as possible?

Comment: The design is fluid and currently for a very wide display the `<input>` will appear on the same line as the `<select>`. Do you _always_ want the `<select>` below or should all 5 elements be allowed to exist on the same line?

Comment: I think I should have focussed more on making the elements appear as per the images. In the actual page, everything exists inside a fixed-width container which ensures the 3 selects are on one line, and the textboxy and button are on the next line.

Comment: Ah OK. I think my solution should still work within a fixed width container. Please comment on my answer if you do not want to add a wrapper to the second line elements and I should be able to come up with something else :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` in the input box to the left, and `float` button to the right. Then add margins until they're lined up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `<input>` and `<button>` to always exist on the line below, the easiest way to do this is wrap them in a container, for example:

```
<div class="search">
    <input type="text" watermarktext="Enter share class name or partial name" value="" name="Search" id="Search" class="search-input watermarkOn">    
    <button id="btnViewResults" type="submit" class="linkButton medium submit"><span><span id="resultCount">View 27090 matches</span></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

with the associated CSS:

```
.search {
    position:relative;
    padding:16px 0;
}

.search button {
    position:absolute;
    right:12px;
}
```

I ended up commenting out a lot of the CSS in your example, since the container now takes care of the padding and positioning. I forked your fiddle into a [**new demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nZUvW/) to demonstrate. This is working for me in IE6/IE7/IE8 and Chrome 14.